# How to represent null value in a union?

Tags: c++, unions

Just for fun, I'm trying to wrap the sqlite API in C++. I want an interface that somewhat resembles jdbc, so I have a `Statement` class, which has methods to bind the `?` joker characters in prepared statements.

I figured I'll represent these parameters in a `union`:

```
union Param
{
    int i;
    double d;
    std::string s;
};
```

These would go into a map with the parameter's index as the key:

```
std::map<int, Param> parammap;
```

So then, I can have the jdbc-like methods:

```
void Statement::SetInt(int idx, int i)
{
    Param p;
    p.i = i;
    parammap.insert(std::make_pair(idx, p));
}
```

This was all good fun, until I found I also want to be able to set NULL values in the DB.

```
stmt.SetInt(1, 15);
stmt.SetString(2, "John Carmack");
stmt.SetNull(3); //uh oh
```

Is there a smart way to implement this in the `union`? How would I represent that?

Comment: Invent a type: `struct Nothing{};` and add it to the union. Look at boost optional and variant.

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to put `std::string` in a union?

Comment: @hvd I have no idea, actually. Is it bad to do so?

Comment: @Innkeeper Even in those cases where the compiler lets you, you have to be *really* careful to make sure you call its constructor and destructor manually at the appropriate times, and things will break badly if you don't get this right. In fact, the docs for `boost::variant`, as mentioned by Marc Glisse, specifically use `std::string` as an example of when to not use a union.

Comment: @hvd Thanks, I'll check how thats implemented then; although I'm afraid it's a bit too advanced for me at this point.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with SQL so I am removing the tag.

Comment: How are you planning to read values out of `parammap` ?

Comment: You could just have `SetNull` make `i = 0`

Comment: You can't have non trivial types in a union (such as `std::string`).

Comment: @W.B. Yes, I learned that shortly after asking this, and used a struct instead.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Using the int set to zero would mean there is no way to tell if a field in the database should be set to 0 or NULL though. A zeroed field wouldn't be selected in a query like 'WHERE ... IS NULL'

Comment: @Inneekper, but regardless of what you put in the union there is no way still no way to tell that. You have to have information somewhere telling you which type is currently stored in the union, so if the union is supposed to be hold "null" then you just indicate that outside of the union.